# Can OpenLayers 4 shift the showing position of overlaying tile map?

Tags: openlayers

I'm now overlaying some tile image maps on basemap, by using OpenLayers 4. But some layer data is not accurate, so feature positions of the layer are little shift from that of basemap. To avoid this, I want to show the layer little shift from original tile position... is it possible in OpenLayers 4?

Comment: better make accurate data which has correct coordinates.